# w1_slave is missing! Having trouble getting a DS18B20 temp sensor to work on rpi3 with raspbian, help would be appreciated

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-3

[image: Breadboard 1]
[image: Breadboard 2]
[image: Breadboard 3]

Attached is an album showing my breadboard which shows how everything is connected. I am following the instructions here:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/

I have everything wired to the best of my ability, though the different size pi cobbler is throwing me off a bit. I did my best to follow the silkscreened print.
When I load w1-gpio and w1-therm, they load successfully. However, when I try to actually access the device as it instructs, instead of seeing a 28-xxxxx device showing up, I see this:

```
root@demeter:/sys/bus/w1/devices# ls
00-800000000000  w1_bus_master1
```

There is no "w1_slave" file underneath it. After a few minutes, I see another device show up...

```
root@demeter:/sys/bus/w1/devices# ls
00-400000000000  00-800000000000  w1_bus_master1
```

Then still another device shows up...

```
root@demeter:/sys/bus/w1/devices# ls
00-400000000000  00-800000000000  00-c00000000000  w1_bus_master1
```

But still, nothing contains the w1_slave file I'm trying to use to read out temperatures.

Does anything stupid seem to be going on with my wiring? Is there something else I need to be doing that isn't mentioned in the article?

Comment: please edit your questions and include the wiring - linking to outside services leaves the links subject to rot.

Comment: Added in the album from imgur.
Should I remove all links?

Comment: Leaving the link to Adafruit is OK, the idea is to avoid link rot and present (here not linked) all the info someone would need to answer your question. You could even remove the link to the sensor as this is a common sensor.

Comment: The idea was to post the pics here not a link to imgur.

Comment: Are you using the high temperature version of the sensor?

Comment: Negative, I am not. This is the normal version.